# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Setting null field in DTO when binding to HTTP POST instead of failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have an HttpPost controller action that takes in a simple form DTO object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Index(ResultQueryForm queryForm)
{
   ...
}

public class ResultQueryForm
{
   public DateTime? TimestampStart { get; set; }
   public DateTime? TimestampEnd { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The DTO object has nullable datetime fields used to create a range.  The reason that it is set to nullable is because the form that is bound to the model is a query form, and the user doesn't have to enter a date value in the form.

The problem I'm running into is that if the user enters an invalid date, i would like the MVC default model binding to provide an error message.  This happens flawlessly if I have a controller action that takes a DateTime? type as a argument, but since I'm passing a *DTO that holds a DateTime? type* the model binding appears to just set the DateTime? variable to null.  This causes unexpected results.

Note:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Index(DateTime? startDate)
{
   // If the user enters an invalid date, the controller action won't even be run because   the MVC model binding will fail and return an error message to the user
}
```

Is there anyway to tell MVC model binding to "fail" if it can't bind the DateTime? value to the form DTO object, instead of just setting it to null?  Is there a better way?  Passing each individual form input to the controller is infeasible, due to the large amount of properties in the form/dto object (I've excluded many of them for easy reading).

Comment: Did you check `ModelState.IsValid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate your model in the controller action.

```
if(!Model.IsValid)
{
  return View(); // ooops didn't work
}
else
{
  return RedirectToAction("Index"); //horray
}
```

Of course you can put whatever you want in there, and return Json object if you want to display it on your page.

Also you need to add `ValidateInput(true)` up the top of your action method like this: `[HttpPost, ValidateInput(true)]`

Comment: What does the ValidateInput(true) attribute do?

Comment: In your model you can specify the validation methods. You can also do [Required] if you want the field to be required. If you had ValidateInput(false) in your action method, it wouldn't respect you validation attributes.Look @olivehour answer. You can combine mine and his to get a nice solution.

Comment: I thought you only had to put [ValidateInput(false)] if you wanted your form to be able to submit HTML text to the action method. I never put [ValidateInput(true)] on my action methods, and ModelState.IsValid still returns false on model-level validation errors.

Comment: oh yeah for Model.IsValid alone you don't need that. But if you want to do some jquery/js validation you do need it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a custom ValidationAttribute for this.

```
[DateTimeFormat(ErrorMessage = "Invalid date format.")]
public DateTime? TimestampStart { get; set; }
[DateTimeFormat(ErrorMessage = "Invalid date format.")]
public DateTime? TimestampEnd { get; set; }


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class DateTimeFormatAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value) {

        // allow null values
        if (value == null) { return true; }

        // when value is not null, try to convert to a DateTime
        DateTime asDateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out asDateTime)) {
            return true; // parsed to datetime successfully
        }
        return false; // value could not be parsed
    }
}
```